# tibble columns with same name

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I'm extracting a repeated string from a folder of html pages using this function:

```
webpage <- "test.html"

testframe <- webpage %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("#234") %>% 
  html_text() %>%
  str_match_all("\\[([^]]+)\\]") %>%
  extract2(1) 
filename <- webpage
frame <- tibble(filename, testframe)
```

Here's a `test.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>Title</title></head>
<body>
<div id="234">       
<script>
var markeredit = 0;
var allmarkers = [];
var markers = [

    [ "foo", 25.25, 36.36, "bar"], [ "so", 12.12, 78.78, "what"]];
var map;
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The resulting tibble has two `testframe` columns--`testframe[,1]` and `testframe[,2]`.

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  filename            testframe[,1]                              [,2]            
  <chr>               <chr>                                      <chr>           
1 test.html "[\n\n\t[ \"foo\", 25.25, 36.36, \"bar\"]" "\n\n\t[ \"foo\…
2 test.html "[ \"so\", 12.12, 78.78, \"what\"]"        " \"so\", 12.12…
```

I want to `select` only one of them, but can't figure out how to isolate it.

Probably there's some foolishness in my original function that leads to the duplication in the first place. Not sure why?

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing the data in one of your test files.

Comment: Thanks @neilfws--I've added test data to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use `bind_cols(filename, testframe)`

Long answer:
There's a hint to the issue in the output you posted:

> A tibble: 2 × 2
>
> filename            testframe[,1]                              [,2]

Why is it showing three columns if it says it's a 2x2 tibble?

Well, if you look at testframe, you'll see it is itself a dataframe. So you're creating a dataframe where one column is a nested dataframe.
Instead of doing that, just bind the columns of testframe with filename (as above).